# Are void custom directives allowed in Angular? And if so how to declare/enable?

Tags: angular

We have a bunch of Angular.js templates (loaded from the server, dynamically compiled) that we would like to re-use in a Angular rewrite of the application.

The templates use many custom directives. And for one particular directive, the element is always expressed as a void element. See example, where the `custom-datasource` is a void element:

```
<div>
    <p>My template</p>
    <custom-datasource name="myds">

    <custom-chart dsname="myds">
        <series name="..."></series>
    </custom-chart>
</div>
```

Angular directive:

```
@Directive({selector: 'custom-datasource'})
export class DatasourceDirective {}
```

In angular.js it seems like these void tags were silently tolerated.

Question: Is there any way to specify that angular should allow void elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not supported.

Every custom element or directive needs to have a proper opening and closing tag

```
<custom-datasource name="myds"></custom-datasource>
```

Angular only supports valid HTML, and according to the spec only a limited set of elements are void elements. Custom tags can't be void elements.

What you could to is to use a valid void element as selector for your custom element. Therefore valid (according to the HTML spec) void elements can be Angular components.

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element
- https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements